# How reading data with pandas.read_csv containing time AM/PM format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I have the following set of data:

```
        Temp    Hi  Low Out Dew Wind    Wind    Wind    Hi  Hi  Wind    Heat    THW THSW            Rain    Solar   Solar   Hi Solar    Heat    Cool    In  In      Wind    Wind    ISS     Arc.
Date    Time    Out Temp    Temp    Hum Pt. Speed   Dir Run Speed   Dir Chill   Index   Index   Index   Bar     Rain    Rate    Rad.    Energy  Rad.    D-D     D-D     Temp    Hum ET  Samp    Tx  Recept  Int.
01/01/15    12:30 a 17.0    17.6    17.0    14  -10.7   30.6    N   15.29   51.5    N   15.7    14.1    10.8    8.3 741.4   0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.028   0.000   26.2    2   0.00    702 1   100.0   30
01/01/15    1:00 a  16.6    17.0    16.6    14  -11.1   27.4    N   13.68   45.1    N   15.3    13.7    10.7    8.1 741.8   0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.037   0.000   25.6    2   0.25    702 1   100.0   30
01/01/15    1:30 a  16.2    16.6    16.1    14  -11.4   24.1    N   12.07   35.4    N   15.0    13.4    10.7    7.9 741.9   0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.044   0.000   25.1    2   0.00    703 1   100.0   30
01/01/15    2:00 a  15.6    16.2    15.6    14  -11.9   17.7    N   8.85    33.8    N   14.6    12.8    11.0    7.8 742.4   0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.057   0.000   24.6    2   0.20    702 1   100.0   30
01/01/15    2:30 a  15.3    15.8    15.3    14  -12.1   16.1    N   8.05    29.0    N   14.4    12.6    11.0    7.7 742.8   0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.063   0.000   24.2    2   0.00    703 1   100.0   30
01/01/15    3:00 a  14.8    15.3    14.8    15  -11.6   20.9    N   10.46   38.6    N   13.4    12.3    10.0    6.9 742.8   0.00    0.0 0   0.00    0   0.073   0.000   23.6    2   0.18    702 1   100.0   30
```

I'm trying to read it but I hace problems with time format, as you can seeI have 12:00 a, 1:00 a ...

I use to read it another similar files (without am/pm format), as follow:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=2,sep='\s+', header=None,
                   index_col=[0,1,2],dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True,
                   infer_datetime_format=True)
```

I was thinking that I could use `date_parser='%D/%M/%Y %I:%M'` instead of `infer_datetime_format=True` but have not sucess.

Some idea?

I tried this, and I think works, but there is a way to read it directly from read_csv?

```
data = pd.read_csv(path+filename, skiprows=2,sep='\s+', header=None,
                  names=['date','hour','ap','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
                         'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
                         'u','v','w','x','y','z','aa','bb','cc'])
```

and thus i create a time array with:

```
time = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + ' ' + data['hour']+data['ap'])
```

and

```
data.index = time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parse_dates` with:

> dict, e.g. {‘foo’ : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call
>   result ‘foo’

and your custom `date_parser` function

Code:

```
def parse_dt(dt, tm, ap):
    return pd.to_datetime(dt + ' ' + tm + ap, dayfirst=True)

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+', skiprows=2, header=None,
                 parse_dates={'ts': [0,1,2] }, date_parser=parse_dt)
```

Output:

```
In [44]: df
Out[44]:
                   ts     3     4     5   6     7     8  9     10    11 ...  \
0 2015-01-01 00:30:00  17.0  17.6  17.0  14 -10.7  30.6  N  15.29  51.5 ...
1 2015-01-01 01:00:00  16.6  17.0  16.6  14 -11.1  27.4  N  13.68  45.1 ...
2 2015-01-01 01:30:00  16.2  16.6  16.1  14 -11.4  24.1  N  12.07  35.4 ...
3 2015-01-01 02:00:00  15.6  16.2  15.6  14 -11.9  17.7  N   8.85  33.8 ...
4 2015-01-01 02:30:00  15.3  15.8  15.3  14 -12.1  16.1  N   8.05  29.0 ...
5 2015-01-01 03:00:00  14.8  15.3  14.8  15 -11.6  20.9  N  10.46  38.6 ...

  22     23   24    25  26    27   28  29     30  31
0  0  0.028  0.0  26.2   2  0.00  702   1  100.0  30
1  0  0.037  0.0  25.6   2  0.25  702   1  100.0  30
2  0  0.044  0.0  25.1   2  0.00  703   1  100.0  30
3  0  0.057  0.0  24.6   2  0.20  702   1  100.0  30
4  0  0.063  0.0  24.2   2  0.00  703   1  100.0  30
5  0  0.073  0.0  23.6   2  0.18  702   1  100.0  30

[6 rows x 30 columns]
```